# Trouble assigning checkbox value to boolean in HTML/JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

As the title says, I'm relatively new to JS, and I'm struggling to assign a checkbox value to a boolean value in my javascript code.

I have this code:

```js
/* clock.js */

(function() {
            var click = new Audio('sounds/click.mp3');
            click.volume = .01;
            var timermode = false;
            var timer = false;
            
      
            
            
  function display(a, n) {
    number = [
      [1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1], // 0
      [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0], // 1
      [1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1], // 2
      [1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1], // 3
      [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0], // 4
      [1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1], // 5
      [1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1], // 6
      [1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0], // 7
      [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], // 8
      [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1]  // 9
    ]

    n = number[n]
    i = 0
    while (i < n.length) {
      crystal = document.getElementById(a + (i + 1))
      if (n[i] === 0) {
        switch(i+1) {
        case 1:
        case 4:
        case 7:
            crystal.style.transform = 'scale(1, 0)';
            break;
        case 2:
        case 3:
        case 5:
        case 6:
            crystal.style.transform = 'scale(0, 1)';
            break;
        }

        click.play();
      }
      else {
        crystal.style.transform = 'scale(1, 1)';
      }
      i++
    }
  }

  function format(value) {
    value = value + ''

    if (value.length === 1) {
      return '0' + value
    }

    return value
  }

  (function update() {
      var timerBtn = document.getElementById("timer1"); 
      if(timerBtn) {
            timerBtn.addEventListener("click", function (evt) { evt.preventDefault(); if(!timer) {timer = document.querySelector("[name=timer1]");} else {timer=null;} console.log(timer); return false; });
            }
            
      if(!timer) {
    date = new Date()
    hours = format(date.getHours())
    minutes = format(date.getMinutes())
    seconds = format(date.getSeconds())

    setTimeout(function() {
      display('a', hours[0])
      display('b', hours[1])
      display('c', minutes[0])
      display('d', minutes[1])
      display('e', seconds[0])
      display('f', seconds[1])
      update()
    }, 1000)
    }
  })()
})()

function toggleFullScreen() {
       if (!document.fullscreenElement &&    // alternative standard method
        !document.mozFullScreenElement && !document.webkitFullscreenElement) {  // current working methods
         if (document.documentElement.requestFullscreen) {
           document.documentElement.requestFullscreen();
         } else if (document.documentElement.mozRequestFullScreen) {
           document.documentElement.mozRequestFullScreen();
         } else if (document.documentElement.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
           document.documentElement.webkitRequestFullscreen(Element.ALLOW_KEYBOARD_INPUT);
         }
       } else {
          if (document.cancelFullScreen) {
             document.cancelFullScreen();
          } else if (document.mozCancelFullScreen) {
             document.mozCancelFullScreen();
          } else if (document.webkitCancelFullScreen) {
            document.webkitCancelFullScreen();
          }
       }
     }
```

```css
/* rtrtclock.css */
html, body, div {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  /*background: rgb(359, 191, 135);*/
  background: rgb(60,60,60);
}

div {
  display: flex;
}

svg {
  flex: 1;
  opacity: 1;
}

.animate {
  transition: all .1s;
  fill: limegreen;

}

.slots {
    
}

#fullscreen {
    display: inline;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
}

button {
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background: none;
    margin: 0;
    display: none;
}

#a1, #b1, #c1, #d1, #e1, #f1 {
    transform-origin: 0px 38px;
}
#a4, #b4, #c4, #d4, #e4, #f4 {
    transform-origin: 0px 52px;
}
#a7, #b7, #c7, #d7, #e7, #f7 {
    transform-origin: 0px 69px;
}

#a2, #a5 {
    transform-origin: 2px 0px;
}
#a3, #a6 {
    transform-origin: 18px 0px;
}
#b2, #b5 {
    transform-origin: 20px 0px;
}
#b3, #b6 {
    transform-origin: 36px 0px;
}
#c2, #c5 {
    transform-origin: 44px 0px;
}
#c3, #c6 {
    transform-origin: 60px 0px;
}
#d2, #d5 {
    transform-origin: 62px 0px;
}
#d3, #d6 {
    transform-origin: 78px 0px;
}
#e2, #e5 {
    transform-origin: 86px 0px;
}
#e3, #e6 {
    transform-origin: 102px 0px;
}
#f2, #f5 {
    transform-origin: 104px 0px;
}
#f3, #f6 {
    transform-origin: 120px 0px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="rtrtclock.css" />
<script src="rtrtclock.js"></script>
  <body>
    <div>
    <button onclick="toggleFullScreen(); return false" id="fullscreen">
        <img src="img/fullscreen.png" alt="Fullscreen"/>
    </button>
    <input type="checkbox" id="timer1" name="timer1" value="Timer">
    <label for="timer1">Timer Mode</label><br>
      <svg id='clock' viewBox='0 36 122 36' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'>
        
        <g id='seconds'>
          <g>
            <path id='f7' class="animate" d='M106,69l3-3h6l3,3c0,0-1,1-3,1h-6C107,70,106,69,106,69z'/>
            <path id='f6' class="animate" d='M119,55l-3,2v8l3,3c0,0,1-1,1-3v-7C120,56,119,55,119,55z'/>
            <path id='f5' class="animate" d='M105,55l3,2v8l-3,3c0,0-1-1-1-3v-7C104,56,105,55,105,55z'/>
            <polygon id='f4' class="animate" points='109,52 115,52 118,54 115,56 109,56 106,54'/>
            <path id='f3' class="animate" d='M119,40l-3,3v8l3,2c0,0,1-1,1-3v-7C120,41,119,40,119,40z'/>
            <path id='f2' class="animate" d='M105,40l3,3v8l-3,2c0,0-1-1-1-3v-7C104,41,105,40,105,40z'/>
            <path id='f1' class="animate" d='M106,39l3,3h6l3-3c0,0-1-1-3-1h-6C107,38,106,39,106,39z'/>
          </g>
          <g>
            <path id='e7' class="animate" d='M88,69l3-3h6l3,3c0,0-1,1-3,1h-6C89,70,88,69,88,69z'/>
            <path id='e6' class="animate" d='M101,55l-3,2v8l3,3c0,0,1-1,1-3v-7C102,56,101,55,101,55z'/>
            <path id='e5' class="animate" d='M87,55l3,2v8l-3,3c0,0-1-1-1-3v-7C86,56,87,55,87,55z'/>
            <polygon id='e4' class="animate" points='91,52 97,52 100,54 97,56 91,56 88,54'/>
            <path id='e3' class="animate" d='M101,40l-3,3v8l3,2c0,0,1-1,1-3v-7C102,41,101,40,101,40z'/>
            <path id='e2' class="animate" d='M87,40l3,3v8l-3,2c0,0-1-1-1-3v-7C86,41,87,40,87,40z'/>
            <path id='e1' class="animate" d='M88,39l3,3h6l3-3c0,0-1-1-3-1h-6C89,38,88,39,88,39z'/>
          </g>
        </g>
        <g id='minutes'>
          <g>
            <path id='d7' class="animate" d='M64,69l3-3h6l3,3c0,0-1,1-3,1h-6C65,70,64,69,64,69z'/>
            <path id='d6' class="animate" d='M77,55l-3,2v8l3,3c0,0,1-1,1-3v-7C78,56,77,55,77,55z'/>
            <path id='d5' class="animate" d='M63,55l3,2v8l-3,3c0,0-1-1-1-3v-7C62,56,63,55,63,55z'/>
            <polygon id='d4' class="animate" points='67,52 73,52 76,54 73,56 67,56 64,54'/>
            <path id='d3' class="animate" d='M77,40l-3,3v8l3,2c0,0,1-1,1-3v-7C78,41,77,40,77,40z'/>
            <path id='d2' class="animate" d='M63,40l3,3v8l-3,2c0,0-1-1-1-3v-7C62,41,63,40,63,40z'/>
            <path id='d1' class="animate" d='M64,39l3,3h6l3-3c0,0-1-1-3-1h-6C65,38,64,39,64,39z'/>
          </g>
          <g>
            <path id='c7' class="animate" d='M46,69l3-3h6l3,3c0,0-1,1-3,1h-6C47,70,46,69,46,69z'/>
            <path id='c6' class="animate" d='M59,55l-3,2v8l3,3c0,0,1-1,1-3v-7C60,56,59,55,59,55z'/>
            <path id='c5' class="animate" d='M45,55l3,2v8l-3,3c0,0-1-1-1-3v-7C44,56,45,55,45,55z'/>
            <polygon id='c4' class="animate" points='49,52 55,52 58,54 55,56 49,56 46,54'/>
            <path id='c3' class="animate" d='M59,40l-3,3v8l3,2c0,0,1-1,1-3v-7C60,41,59,40,59,40z'/>
            <path id='c2' class="animate" d='M45,40l3,3v8l-3,2c0,0-1-1-1-3v-7C44,41,45,40,45,40z'/>
            <path id='c1' class="animate" d='M46,39l3,3h6l3-3c0,0-1-1-3-1h-6C47,38,46,39,46,39z'/>
          </g>
        </g>
        <g id='hours'>
          <g>
            <path id='b7' class="animate" d='M22,69l3-3h6l3,3c0,0-1,1-3,1h-6C23,70,22,69,22,69z'/>
            <path id='b6' class="animate" d='M35,55l-3,2v8l3,3c0,0,1-1,1-3v-7C36,56,35,55,35,55z'/>
            <path id='b5' class="animate" d='M21,55l3,2v8l-3,3c0,0-1-1-1-3v-7C20,56,21,55,21,55z'/>
            <polygon id='b4' class="animate" points='25,52 31,52 34,54 31,56 25,56 22,54'/>
            <path id='b3' class="animate" d='M35,40l-3,3v8l3,2c0,0,1-1,1-3v-7C36,41,35,40,35,40z'/>
            <path id='b2' class="animate" d='M21,40l3,3v8l-3,2c0,0-1-1-1-3v-7C20,41,21,40,21,40z'/>
            <path id='b1' class="animate" d='M22,39l3,3h6l3-3c0,0-1-1-3-1h-6C23,38,22,39,22,39z'/>
          </g>
          <g>
            <path id='a7' class="animate" d='M4,69l3-3h6l3,3c0,0-1,1-3,1h-6C5,70,4,69,4,69z'/>
            <path id='a6' class="animate" d='M17,55l-3,2v8l3,3c0,0,1-1,1-3v-7C18,56,17,55,17,55z'/>
            <path id='a5' class="animate" d='M3,55l3,2v8l-3,3c0,0-1-1-1-3v-7C2,56,3,55,3,55z'/>
            <polygon id='a4' class="animate" points='7,52 13,52 16,54 13,56 7,56 4,54'/>
            <path id='a3' class="animate" d='M17,40l-3,3v8l3,2c0,0,1-1,1-3v-7C18,41,17,40,17,40z'/>
            <path id='a2' class="animate" d='M3,40l3,3v8l-3,2c0,0-1-1-1-3v-7C2,41,3,40,3,40z'/>
            <path id='a1' class="animate" d='M4,39l3,3h6l3-3c0,0-1-1-3-1h-6C5,38,4,39,4,39z'/>
          </g>
        </g>
        <g id='dots'>
          <g>
            <circle class="animate" cx='82' cy='54' r='2'/>
        
          </g>
          <g>
            <circle class="animate" cx='40' cy='50' r='2'/>
            <circle class="animate" cx='40' cy='58' r='2'/>
          </g>
        </g>
        <!--<g id='secondslots'>
          <g>
            <path id='f7' class="slots" d='M106,69l3-3h6l3,3c0,0-1,1-3,1h-6C107,70,106,69,106,69z'/>
            <path id='f6' class="slots" d='M119,55l-3,2v8l3,3c0,0,1-1,1-3v-7C120,56,119,55,119,55z'/>
            <path id='f5' class="slots" d='M105,55l3,2v8l-3,3c0,0-1-1-1-3v-7C104,56,105,55,105,55z'/>
            <polygon id='f4' class="slots" points='109,52 115,52 118,54 115,56 109,56 106,54'/>
            <path id='f3' class="slots" d='M119,40l-3,3v8l3,2c0,0,1-1,1-3v-7C120,41,119,40,119,40z'/>
            <path id='f2' class="slots" d='M105,40l3,3v8l-3,2c0,0-1-1-1-3v-7C104,41,105,40,105,40z'/>
            <path id='f1' class="slots" d='M106,39l3,3h6l3-3c0,0-1-1-3-1h-6C107,38,106,39,106,39z'/>
          </g>
          <g>
            <path id='e7' class="slots" d='M88,69l3-3h6l3,3c0,0-1,1-3,1h-6C89,70,88,69,88,69z'/>
            <path id='e6' class="slots" d='M101,55l-3,2v8l3,3c0,0,1-1,1-3v-7C102,56,101,55,101,55z'/>
            <path id='e5' class="slots" d='M87,55l3,2v8l-3,3c0,0-1-1-1-3v-7C86,56,87,55,87,55z'/>
            <polygon id='e4' class="slots" points='91,52 97,52 100,54 97,56 91,56 88,54'/>
            <path id='e3' class="slots" d='M101,40l-3,3v8l3,2c0,0,1-1,1-3v-7C102,41,101,40,101,40z'/>
            <path id='e2' class="slots" d='M87,40l3,3v8l-3,2c0,0-1-1-1-3v-7C86,41,87,40,87,40z'/>
            <path id='e1' class="slots" d='M88,39l3,3h6l3-3c0,0-1-1-3-1h-6C89,38,88,39,88,39z'/>
          </g>
        </g>
        <g id='minuteslots'>
          <g>
            <path id='d7' class="slots" d='M64,69l3-3h6l3,3c0,0-1,1-3,1h-6C65,70,64,69,64,69z'/>
            <path id='d6' class="slots" d='M77,55l-3,2v8l3,3c0,0,1-1,1-3v-7C78,56,77,55,77,55z'/>
            <path id='d5' class="slots" d='M63,55l3,2v8l-3,3c0,0-1-1-1-3v-7C62,56,63,55,63,55z'/>
            <polygon id='d4' class="slots" points='67,52 73,52 76,54 73,56 67,56 64,54'/>
            <path id='d3' class="slots" d='M77,40l-3,3v8l3,2c0,0,1-1,1-3v-7C78,41,77,40,77,40z'/>
            <path id='d2' class="slots" d='M63,40l3,3v8l-3,2c0,0-1-1-1-3v-7C62,41,63,40,63,40z'/>
            <path id='d1' class="slots" d='M64,39l3,3h6l3-3c0,0-1-1-3-1h-6C65,38,64,39,64,39z'/>
          </g>
          <g>
            <path id='c7' class="slots" d='M46,69l3-3h6l3,3c0,0-1,1-3,1h-6C47,70,46,69,46,69z'/>
            <path id='c6' class="slots" d='M59,55l-3,2v8l3,3c0,0,1-1,1-3v-7C60,56,59,55,59,55z'/>
            <path id='c5' class="slots" d='M45,55l3,2v8l-3,3c0,0-1-1-1-3v-7C44,56,45,55,45,55z'/>
            <polygon id='c4' class="slots" points='49,52 55,52 58,54 55,56 49,56 46,54'/>
            <path id='c3' class="slots" d='M59,40l-3,3v8l3,2c0,0,1-1,1-3v-7C60,41,59,40,59,40z'/>
            <path id='c2' class="slots" d='M45,40l3,3v8l-3,2c0,0-1-1-1-3v-7C44,41,45,40,45,40z'/>
            <path id='c1' class="slots" d='M46,39l3,3h6l3-3c0,0-1-1-3-1h-6C47,38,46,39,46,39z'/>
          </g>
        </g>
        <g id='hourslots'>
          <g>
            <path id='b7' class="slots" d='M22,69l3-3h6l3,3c0,0-1,1-3,1h-6C23,70,22,69,22,69z'/>
            <path id='b6' class="slots" d='M35,55l-3,2v8l3,3c0,0,1-1,1-3v-7C36,56,35,55,35,55z'/>
            <path id='b5' class="slots" d='M21,55l3,2v8l-3,3c0,0-1-1-1-3v-7C20,56,21,55,21,55z'/>
            <polygon id='b4' class="slots" points='25,52 31,52 34,54 31,56 25,56 22,54'/>
            <path id='b3' class="slots" d='M35,40l-3,3v8l3,2c0,0,1-1,1-3v-7C36,41,35,40,35,40z'/>
            <path id='b2' class="slots" d='M21,40l3,3v8l-3,2c0,0-1-1-1-3v-7C20,41,21,40,21,40z'/>
            <path id='b1' class="slots" d='M22,39l3,3h6l3-3c0,0-1-1-3-1h-6C23,38,22,39,22,39z'/>
          </g>
          <g>
            <path id='a7' class="slots" d='M4,69l3-3h6l3,3c0,0-1,1-3,1h-6C5,70,4,69,4,69z'/>
            <path id='a6' class="slots" d='M17,55l-3,2v8l3,3c0,0,1-1,1-3v-7C18,56,17,55,17,55z'/>
            <path id='a5' class="slots" d='M3,55l3,2v8l-3,3c0,0-1-1-1-3v-7C2,56,3,55,3,55z'/>
            <polygon id='a4' class="slots" points='7,52 13,52 16,54 13,56 7,56 4,54'/>
            <path id='a3' class="slots" d='M17,40l-3,3v8l3,2c0,0,1-1,1-3v-7C18,41,17,40,17,40z'/>
            <path id='a2' class="slots" d='M3,40l3,3v8l-3,2c0,0-1-1-1-3v-7C2,41,3,40,3,40z'/>
            <path id='a1' class="slots" d='M4,39l3,3h6l3-3c0,0-1-1-3-1h-6C5,38,4,39,4,39z'/>
          </g>
        </g>-->
      </svg>
      </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

And my goal is to make the checkbox convert it from a clock to a timer. With the current code, the checkbox doesn't even seem to check when I click it, although I know it's receiving some sort of input due to the console. What am I missing?

Comment: It's this code here. `timerBtn.addEventListener("click", function (evt) { evt.preventDefault();` remove the call to `preventDefault`. It's stopping the browser from performing the default actions when your checkbox is clicked. One of those actions is to check the box. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Don't call [`Event.preventDefault()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) in the `click` event listener; it prevents the checkbox from being checked thus causing the `checked` property to always be `false`:

```js
/* clock.js */

(function() {
  var click = new Audio('sounds/click.mp3');
  click.volume = .01;
  var timermode = false;
  var timer = false;




  function display(a, n) {
    number = [
      [1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1], // 0
      [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0], // 1
      [1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1], // 2
      [1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1], // 3
      [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0], // 4
      [1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1], // 5
      [1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1], // 6
      [1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0], // 7
      [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], // 8
      [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1] // 9
    ]

    n = number[n]
    i = 0
    while (i < n.length) {
      crystal = document.getElementById(a + (i + 1))
      if (n[i] === 0) {
        switch (i + 1) {
          case 1:
          case 4:
          case 7:
            crystal.style.transform = 'scale(1, 0)';
            break;
          case 2:
          case 3:
          case 5:
          case 6:
            crystal.style.transform = 'scale(0, 1)';
            break;
        }

        click.play();
      } else {
        crystal.style.transform = 'scale(1, 1)';
      }
      i++
    }
  }

  function format(value) {
    value = value + ''

    if (value.length === 1) {
      return '0' + value
    }

    return value
  }

  (function update() {
    var timerBtn = document.getElementById("timer1");
    if (timerBtn) {
      timerBtn.addEventListener("click", function(evt) {
        if (!timer) {
          timer = document.querySelector("[name=timer1]");
        } else {
          timer = null;
        }
        console.log(timer);
        return false;
      });
    }

    if (!timer) {
      date = new Date()
      hours = format(date.getHours())
      minutes = format(date.getMinutes())
      seconds = format(date.getSeconds())

      setTimeout(function() {
        display('a', hours[0])
        display('b', hours[1])
        display('c', minutes[0])
        display('d', minutes[1])
        display('e', seconds[0])
        display('f', seconds[1])
        update()
      }, 1000)
    }
  })()
})()

function toggleFullScreen() {
  if (!document.fullscreenElement && // alternative standard method
    !document.mozFullScreenElement && !document.webkitFullscreenElement) { // current working methods
    if (document.documentElement.requestFullscreen) {
      document.documentElement.requestFullscreen();
    } else if (document.documentElement.mozRequestFullScreen) {
      document.documentElement.mozRequestFullScreen();
    } else if (document.documentElement.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
      document.documentElement.webkitRequestFullscreen(Element.ALLOW_KEYBOARD_INPUT);
    }
  } else {
    if (document.cancelFullScreen) {
      document.cancelFullScreen();
    } else if (document.mozCancelFullScreen) {
      document.mozCancelFullScreen();
    } else if (document.webkitCancelFullScreen) {
      document.webkitCancelFullScreen();
    }
  }
}
```

```css
/* rtrtclock.css */

html,
body,
div {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  /*background: rgb(359, 191, 135);*/
  background: rgb(60, 60, 60);
}

div {
  display: flex;
}

svg {
  flex: 1;
  opacity: 1;
}

.animate {
  transition: all .1s;
  fill: limegreen;
}

.slots {}

#fullscreen {
  display: inline;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
}

button {
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: none;
  margin: 0;
  display: none;
}

#a1,
#b1,
#c1,
#d1,
#e1,
#f1 {
  transform-origin: 0px 38px;
}

#a4,
#b4,
#c4,
#d4,
#e4,
#f4 {
  transform-origin: 0px 52px;
}

#a7,
#b7,
#c7,
#d7,
#e7,
#f7 {
  transform-origin: 0px 69px;
}

#a2,
#a5 {
  transform-origin: 2px 0px;
}

#a3,
#a6 {
  transform-origin: 18px 0px;
}

#b2,
#b5 {
  transform-origin: 20px 0px;
}

#b3,
#b6 {
  transform-origin: 36px 0px;
}

#c2,
#c5 {
  transform-origin: 44px 0px;
}

#c3,
#c6 {
  transform-origin: 60px 0px;
}

#d2,
#d5 {
  transform-origin: 62px 0px;
}

#d3,
#d6 {
  transform-origin: 78px 0px;
}

#e2,
#e5 {
  transform-origin: 86px 0px;
}

#e3,
#e6 {
  transform-origin: 102px 0px;
}

#f2,
#f5 {
  transform-origin: 104px 0px;
}

#f3,
#f6 {
  transform-origin: 120px 0px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
</head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="rtrtclock.css" />
<script src="rtrtclock.js"></script>

<body>
  <div>
    <button onclick="toggleFullScreen(); return false" id="fullscreen">
        <img src="img/fullscreen.png" alt="Fullscreen"/>
    </button>
    <input type="checkbox" id="timer1" name="timer1" value="Timer">
    <label for="timer1">Timer Mode</label><br>
    <svg id='clock' viewBox='0 36 122 36' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'>
        
        <g id='seconds'>
          <g>
            <path id='f7' class="animate" d='M106,69l3-3h6l3,3c0,0-1,1-3,1h-6C107,70,106,69,106,69z'/>
            <path id='f6' class="animate" d='M119,55l-3,2v8l3,3c0,0,1-1,1-3v-7C120,56,119,55,119,55z'/>
            <path id='f5' class="animate" d='M105,55l3,2v8l-3,3c0,0-1-1-1-3v-7C104,56,105,55,105,55z'/>
            <polygon id='f4' class="animate" points='109,52 115,52 118,54 115,56 109,56 106,54'/>
            <path id='f3' class="animate" d='M119,40l-3,3v8l3,2c0,0,1-1,1-3v-7C120,41,119,40,119,40z'/>
            <path id='f2' class="animate" d='M105,40l3,3v8l-3,2c0,0-1-1-1-3v-7C104,41,105,40,105,40z'/>
            <path id='f1' class="animate" d='M106,39l3,3h6l3-3c0,0-1-1-3-1h-6C107,38,106,39,106,39z'/>
          </g>
          <g>
            <path id='e7' class="animate" d='M88,69l3-3h6l3,3c0,0-1,1-3,1h-6C89,70,88,69,88,69z'/>
            <path id='e6' class="animate" d='M101,55l-3,2v8l3,3c0,0,1-1,1-3v-7C102,56,101,55,101,55z'/>
            <path id='e5' class="animate" d='M87,55l3,2v8l-3,3c0,0-1-1-1-3v-7C86,56,87,55,87,55z'/>
            <polygon id='e4' class="animate" points='91,52 97,52 100,54 97,56 91,56 88,54'/>
            <path id='e3' class="animate" d='M101,40l-3,3v8l3,2c0,0,1-1,1-3v-7C102,41,101,40,101,40z'/>
            <path id='e2' class="animate" d='M87,40l3,3v8l-3,2c0,0-1-1-1-3v-7C86,41,87,40,87,40z'/>
            <path id='e1' class="animate" d='M88,39l3,3h6l3-3c0,0-1-1-3-1h-6C89,38,88,39,88,39z'/>
          </g>
        </g>
        <g id='minutes'>
          <g>
            <path id='d7' class="animate" d='M64,69l3-3h6l3,3c0,0-1,1-3,1h-6C65,70,64,69,64,69z'/>
            <path id='d6' class="animate" d='M77,55l-3,2v8l3,3c0,0,1-1,1-3v-7C78,56,77,55,77,55z'/>
            <path id='d5' class="animate" d='M63,55l3,2v8l-3,3c0,0-1-1-1-3v-7C62,56,63,55,63,55z'/>
            <polygon id='d4' class="animate" points='67,52 73,52 76,54 73,56 67,56 64,54'/>
            <path id='d3' class="animate" d='M77,40l-3,3v8l3,2c0,0,1-1,1-3v-7C78,41,77,40,77,40z'/>
            <path id='d2' class="animate" d='M63,40l3,3v8l-3,2c0,0-1-1-1-3v-7C62,41,63,40,63,40z'/>
            <path id='d1' class="animate" d='M64,39l3,3h6l3-3c0,0-1-1-3-1h-6C65,38,64,39,64,39z'/>
          </g>
          <g>
            <path id='c7' class="animate" d='M46,69l3-3h6l3,3c0,0-1,1-3,1h-6C47,70,46,69,46,69z'/>
            <path id='c6' class="animate" d='M59,55l-3,2v8l3,3c0,0,1-1,1-3v-7C60,56,59,55,59,55z'/>
            <path id='c5' class="animate" d='M45,55l3,2v8l-3,3c0,0-1-1-1-3v-7C44,56,45,55,45,55z'/>
            <polygon id='c4' class="animate" points='49,52 55,52 58,54 55,56 49,56 46,54'/>
            <path id='c3' class="animate" d='M59,40l-3,3v8l3,2c0,0,1-1,1-3v-7C60,41,59,40,59,40z'/>
            <path id='c2' class="animate" d='M45,40l3,3v8l-3,2c0,0-1-1-1-3v-7C44,41,45,40,45,40z'/>
            <path id='c1' class="animate" d='M46,39l3,3h6l3-3c0,0-1-1-3-1h-6C47,38,46,39,46,39z'/>
          </g>
        </g>
        <g id='hours'>
          <g>
            <path id='b7' class="animate" d='M22,69l3-3h6l3,3c0,0-1,1-3,1h-6C23,70,22,69,22,69z'/>
            <path id='b6' class="animate" d='M35,55l-3,2v8l3,3c0,0,1-1,1-3v-7C36,56,35,55,35,55z'/>
            <path id='b5' class="animate" d='M21,55l3,2v8l-3,3c0,0-1-1-1-3v-7C20,56,21,55,21,55z'/>
            <polygon id='b4' class="animate" points='25,52 31,52 34,54 31,56 25,56 22,54'/>
            <path id='b3' class="animate" d='M35,40l-3,3v8l3,2c0,0,1-1,1-3v-7C36,41,35,40,35,40z'/>
            <path id='b2' class="animate" d='M21,40l3,3v8l-3,2c0,0-1-1-1-3v-7C20,41,21,40,21,40z'/>
            <path id='b1' class="animate" d='M22,39l3,3h6l3-3c0,0-1-1-3-1h-6C23,38,22,39,22,39z'/>
          </g>
          <g>
            <path id='a7' class="animate" d='M4,69l3-3h6l3,3c0,0-1,1-3,1h-6C5,70,4,69,4,69z'/>
            <path id='a6' class="animate" d='M17,55l-3,2v8l3,3c0,0,1-1,1-3v-7C18,56,17,55,17,55z'/>
            <path id='a5' class="animate" d='M3,55l3,2v8l-3,3c0,0-1-1-1-3v-7C2,56,3,55,3,55z'/>
            <polygon id='a4' class="animate" points='7,52 13,52 16,54 13,56 7,56 4,54'/>
            <path id='a3' class="animate" d='M17,40l-3,3v8l3,2c0,0,1-1,1-3v-7C18,41,17,40,17,40z'/>
            <path id='a2' class="animate" d='M3,40l3,3v8l-3,2c0,0-1-1-1-3v-7C2,41,3,40,3,40z'/>
            <path id='a1' class="animate" d='M4,39l3,3h6l3-3c0,0-1-1-3-1h-6C5,38,4,39,4,39z'/>
          </g>
        </g>
        <g id='dots'>
          <g>
            <circle class="animate" cx='82' cy='54' r='2'/>
        
          </g>
          <g>
            <circle class="animate" cx='40' cy='50' r='2'/>
            <circle class="animate" cx='40' cy='58' r='2'/>
          </g>
        </g>
        <!--<g id='secondslots'>
          <g>
            <path id='f7' class="slots" d='M106,69l3-3h6l3,3c0,0-1,1-3,1h-6C107,70,106,69,106,69z'/>
            <path id='f6' class="slots" d='M119,55l-3,2v8l3,3c0,0,1-1,1-3v-7C120,56,119,55,119,55z'/>
            <path id='f5' class="slots" d='M105,55l3,2v8l-3,3c0,0-1-1-1-3v-7C104,56,105,55,105,55z'/>
            <polygon id='f4' class="slots" points='109,52 115,52 118,54 115,56 109,56 106,54'/>
            <path id='f3' class="slots" d='M119,40l-3,3v8l3,2c0,0,1-1,1-3v-7C120,41,119,40,119,40z'/>
            <path id='f2' class="slots" d='M105,40l3,3v8l-3,2c0,0-1-1-1-3v-7C104,41,105,40,105,40z'/>
            <path id='f1' class="slots" d='M106,39l3,3h6l3-3c0,0-1-1-3-1h-6C107,38,106,39,106,39z'/>
          </g>
          <g>
            <path id='e7' class="slots" d='M88,69l3-3h6l3,3c0,0-1,1-3,1h-6C89,70,88,69,88,69z'/>
            <path id='e6' class="slots" d='M101,55l-3,2v8l3,3c0,0,1-1,1-3v-7C102,56,101,55,101,55z'/>
            <path id='e5' class="slots" d='M87,55l3,2v8l-3,3c0,0-1-1-1-3v-7C86,56,87,55,87,55z'/>
            <polygon id='e4' class="slots" points='91,52 97,52 100,54 97,56 91,56 88,54'/>
            <path id='e3' class="slots" d='M101,40l-3,3v8l3,2c0,0,1-1,1-3v-7C102,41,101,40,101,40z'/>
            <path id='e2' class="slots" d='M87,40l3,3v8l-3,2c0,0-1-1-1-3v-7C86,41,87,40,87,40z'/>
            <path id='e1' class="slots" d='M88,39l3,3h6l3-3c0,0-1-1-3-1h-6C89,38,88,39,88,39z'/>
          </g>
        </g>
        <g id='minuteslots'>
          <g>
            <path id='d7' class="slots" d='M64,69l3-3h6l3,3c0,0-1,1-3,1h-6C65,70,64,69,64,69z'/>
            <path id='d6' class="slots" d='M77,55l-3,2v8l3,3c0,0,1-1,1-3v-7C78,56,77,55,77,55z'/>
            <path id='d5' class="slots" d='M63,55l3,2v8l-3,3c0,0-1-1-1-3v-7C62,56,63,55,63,55z'/>
            <polygon id='d4' class="slots" points='67,52 73,52 76,54 73,56 67,56 64,54'/>
            <path id='d3' class="slots" d='M77,40l-3,3v8l3,2c0,0,1-1,1-3v-7C78,41,77,40,77,40z'/>
            <path id='d2' class="slots" d='M63,40l3,3v8l-3,2c0,0-1-1-1-3v-7C62,41,63,40,63,40z'/>
            <path id='d1' class="slots" d='M64,39l3,3h6l3-3c0,0-1-1-3-1h-6C65,38,64,39,64,39z'/>
          </g>
          <g>
            <path id='c7' class="slots" d='M46,69l3-3h6l3,3c0,0-1,1-3,1h-6C47,70,46,69,46,69z'/>
            <path id='c6' class="slots" d='M59,55l-3,2v8l3,3c0,0,1-1,1-3v-7C60,56,59,55,59,55z'/>
            <path id='c5' class="slots" d='M45,55l3,2v8l-3,3c0,0-1-1-1-3v-7C44,56,45,55,45,55z'/>
            <polygon id='c4' class="slots" points='49,52 55,52 58,54 55,56 49,56 46,54'/>
            <path id='c3' class="slots" d='M59,40l-3,3v8l3,2c0,0,1-1,1-3v-7C60,41,59,40,59,40z'/>
            <path id='c2' class="slots" d='M45,40l3,3v8l-3,2c0,0-1-1-1-3v-7C44,41,45,40,45,40z'/>
            <path id='c1' class="slots" d='M46,39l3,3h6l3-3c0,0-1-1-3-1h-6C47,38,46,39,46,39z'/>
          </g>
        </g>
        <g id='hourslots'>
          <g>
            <path id='b7' class="slots" d='M22,69l3-3h6l3,3c0,0-1,1-3,1h-6C23,70,22,69,22,69z'/>
            <path id='b6' class="slots" d='M35,55l-3,2v8l3,3c0,0,1-1,1-3v-7C36,56,35,55,35,55z'/>
            <path id='b5' class="slots" d='M21,55l3,2v8l-3,3c0,0-1-1-1-3v-7C20,56,21,55,21,55z'/>
            <polygon id='b4' class="slots" points='25,52 31,52 34,54 31,56 25,56 22,54'/>
            <path id='b3' class="slots" d='M35,40l-3,3v8l3,2c0,0,1-1,1-3v-7C36,41,35,40,35,40z'/>
            <path id='b2' class="slots" d='M21,40l3,3v8l-3,2c0,0-1-1-1-3v-7C20,41,21,40,21,40z'/>
            <path id='b1' class="slots" d='M22,39l3,3h6l3-3c0,0-1-1-3-1h-6C23,38,22,39,22,39z'/>
          </g>
          <g>
            <path id='a7' class="slots" d='M4,69l3-3h6l3,3c0,0-1,1-3,1h-6C5,70,4,69,4,69z'/>
            <path id='a6' class="slots" d='M17,55l-3,2v8l3,3c0,0,1-1,1-3v-7C18,56,17,55,17,55z'/>
            <path id='a5' class="slots" d='M3,55l3,2v8l-3,3c0,0-1-1-1-3v-7C2,56,3,55,3,55z'/>
            <polygon id='a4' class="slots" points='7,52 13,52 16,54 13,56 7,56 4,54'/>
            <path id='a3' class="slots" d='M17,40l-3,3v8l3,2c0,0,1-1,1-3v-7C18,41,17,40,17,40z'/>
            <path id='a2' class="slots" d='M3,40l3,3v8l-3,2c0,0-1-1-1-3v-7C2,41,3,40,3,40z'/>
            <path id='a1' class="slots" d='M4,39l3,3h6l3-3c0,0-1-1-3-1h-6C5,38,4,39,4,39z'/>
          </g>
        </g>-->
      </svg>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This fixes the issue of the checkbox not displaying, but the variable still doesn't appear to be being updated correctly. Could it be because of where I have the code to check for the click?